# iPhone JSON Framework not parsing JSON string object not within an object or array

Tags: iphone, ios, json, json-framework

I'm using the JSON framework in Obj-C (iOS) to parse responses from a RESTful webservice (C#/.NET).

The framework is fine when it comes to arrays or objects, but one of the service calls is returning a string:

Raw value (in memory on the server):
    `41SIdX1GRoyw1174duOrewErZpn/WatH`

JSON value in the http response once encoded by WCF:
`"41SIdX1GRoyw1174duOrewErZpn\/WatH"`

This is processed OK by counterpart JSON frameworks on Android, Windows Phone 7 and, of course, jQuery. The server also sometimes returns a .NET WebFaultException, which would automatically serialize an error message as `"Error message here"`.

The JSON Framework comes back with an error: `Token 'string' not expected before outer-most array or object`

Anyone know how can I decode a javascript string in Objective C?

thanks
Kris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're saying that the JSON framework you're using can't handle a *value* as the outermost entity in a JSON string -- it expects an object or array.  If that's the case, it would be a simple matter to test the first non-whitespace character for either '[' or '{', and, if not one of those, assume it's a value.

Simpler still, you could always enclose the input string in '[' ']' before feeding it to the JSON parser, then "discard" the outer one-element array before observing the data.  This lets the JSON parser handle parsing whatever value format is present.

Comment: Hi there, on the former, the problem is really that the value is JSON formatted (i.e., with escape characters), so I could get the value this way, but still left with the problem of decoding which is dealt with by your 2nd point - it's a bit hacky - but it'll work! It's strange that the framework cannot deal with this scenario, as it obviously has the capability to deal with javascript-escaped strings. thanks,k

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString*)handleResponseAsString:(NSString*)data{
if(data==nil || [data length] == 0) return nil;
NSString* retVal = nil;
SBJsonParser* parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSArray* items = [parser objectWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]", data]]; // enclose in [] so that the parser thinks it's an array
if([parser error] == nil)
{
    if([items count] > 0) retVal = (NSString*) [items objectAtIndex:0];
    else NSLog(@"handleResponseAsString parser error: the array had zero elements");
}else{
    NSLog(@"handleResponseAsString error: '%@' could not be decoded due to error: %@", data, [parser error]);
}
[parser release];
return retVal;
```

}